# How to call and run Python file on raspberry pi using web based Button?

Tags: python, pi-3, web-server, php

I have created .py file that is doing job of communicating on UART quite well. Now I want to run that file on button clicking from browser. I have tried exec("python filename.py"); in PHP but that didn't worked. I have also tried system().

Comment: Can you give more details ? Is this python script like a daemon or it simply exits after doing some tasks?  Which web server are you running on PI ?

Comment: Perhaps this is something that you could do using [Remi](https://github.com/dddomodossola/remi)? Certainly if you're just wanting a single-use website with a button that is used to run your script that's one of the easiest ways (it's all done with Python too).

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how to did it with cherrypy3 on a raspbian jessie.

- Install cherrypy3 with `sudo apt install python-cherrypy3`.
- Create a file `button.py` with the following content:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  # coding: utf-8

  import cherrypy
  import subprocess

  text = """
  <html><body>
  <form method='get' action='do_it'>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
  </form></body>
  {}
  </html>
  """


  class PiButton(object):
      @cherrypy.expose
      def index(self):
          return text.format("")

      @cherrypy.expose
      def do_it(self, *vargs, **kwargs):
          #command = "ls /"
          command = "python my_other_python.script.py"
          result = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '<br>')
          result2 = "command: {!r}<br>result:<br>{}".format(command, result)
          return text.format(result2)


      if __name__ == "__main__":
          cherrypy.engine.autoreload.unsubscribe()
          cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': "0.0.0.0", 'server.socket_port': 8181})
          cherrypy.quickstart(PiButton(), '/', {'':{}})
  ```
- Run it with `python button.py`
- Now open a browser and enter the adress: `http://<ip-of-raspberrypi>:8181` replace `<ip-of-raspberrypi>` with the actual IP of your raspberrypi.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making the button redirect the URL to making it have a `location.href?CommandVariable=`

Then, using PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['CommandVariable']))
{
    exec( "python filename.py" );
}
```

This is basically saying: When I push the button, I will place a command variable in the URL. And the PHP will say: Is the Command Variable there? It is? Ok now I can execute this line of code.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to write an sh script that looks like

python path/to/the/pyton/filename.py

And run that.

Comment: But he want to have it run from a button on a web page...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655095/how-to-execute-sh-file-with-php-via-website